# can't use ngSmoothScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

This must be a really simple issue but I can't solve it.

I keep getting this error (unknown provider):

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=smoothScrollProvider%20%3C-<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">moothScroll%20%3C-%20QuizCtrl`

I Installed "ngSmoothScroll": "~2.0.0" with Bower.

I just have this in my controller, and it causes the error.

`QuizApp.controller('QuizCtrl', ['smoothScroll', function(smoothScroll) {...`

It's loading angular-smooth-scroll.js in my index, everything fine.

What is causing that error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I need to include 'smoothScroll' as a dependency in the module too and I was including only in the controller.